# How do you calculate rolls for attacking?

Tags: l5r, attack-roll

I think you calculate your attack rolls as your Agility + Skill for the "roll" and "keep" 2.

How do you increase the "keep"?  A 6k2 rarely hits anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You sum your Agility trait with your weapon skill for the "roll", and "keep" your Agility trait.

So if you have **Agility 2** and Kenjutsu 3, you would roll 5**k2** for attacking with a *katana*.

For *ranged* weapons, replace Agility by Reflexes. For other *melee* weapons, replace the Kenjutsu skill for the skill of that weapon type.

This is normally explained on the *Book of Earth - General Mechanics* regarding skill rolls:

> EXAMPLE: John’s character Bayushi Shinai is going to fire an arrow at an enemy samurai. The Skill that governs archery is Kyujutsu, which is usually paired with Reflexes. **Shinai has Reflexes 3 and Kyujutsu 4, so he rolls 7 dice (3+4)**. John rolls seven ten-sided dice and gets a 2, 4, 5, 7, 7, 8, and a 12 (a 10 that was rolled again to get a 2). John may **keep 3 dice with his Reflexes of 3**, and chooses to keep the 7, 8, and 12 to get a total of 27. Since his Game Master had announced the TN for the shot was 20, Shinai has struck his target.

There are a couple of ways to increase the amount of die kept during an attack roll, such as:

- **Void Point**: You may spend a void point to increase any roll by **+1k1**.
- **Full Attack** (Ring of Fire stance): You may only take Simple or Complex Actions to make attacks, and may only use Move Actions to get closer to your enemies. **You gain +2k1 on all attack rolls**, but take a -10 Armor TN.
- **Center** (Ring of Void stance): You forfeit your current action to gain **+1k1** plus Void Ring on any roll on the following turn.
- A couple of school techniques from the varied clans, such as the *Way of the Crane*, which grants **+1k1** on all attack and focus rolls while assuming the Center Stance.
- **Chosen by the Oracles** advantage: You pick a Ring, and all rolls made using that ring gain **+1k1**, so all you have to do is pick the Fire Ring (for Agility checks).
- **Inheritance** advantage: You gained an heirloom from your family, if this was a katana, all Kenjutsu rolls with that item gain **+1k1**.

Also, for every two extra die above 10 that should be rolled, you convert the extra die to "kept" die. So, if you would roll 12k3, that is converted to 10k4.

### Increasing the odds of success

Just to clarify on the "rarely hits anything", the roll and keep dice system produces a [bell curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bell_Curve), which means that your odds of obtaining a specific number is higher towards the middle of the possible results, and lower towards the minimum and maximum results. So, the more die you roll, even if you only keep two die, the higher the average result.

In other words, the odds of obtaining a 20 (10+10) are higher if you roll more die. Keeping more die, though, both increases the average result and increases the maximum result (30 for k3).

If you try [this proprosed formula](http://anydice.com/articles/legend-of-the-five-rings) on [anydice.com](http://anydice.com/), you will notice that **6k2** will produce a higher average around **17-19**. While **6k3** has a higher average around **23-26**.

Comment: Kenjutsu governs sword weapons, not *all* melee weapons.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure which version of L5R you are talking about, but as far as I know, they all use the same basic mechanics...any attack roll is resolved as a normal skill check, using the skill for the weapon. So, for instance, attacking with a Katana will use Agility + Kenjutsu for the roll, and keep your Agility. For a starting character, the average Agility is 2, but could be anywhere from 1 to 4.

The dice kept for damage tends to be fixed by the type of weapon, and a Katana is usually Strength+1k2.